# Fix white space line in list

Tags: css, list, html-lists, whitespace, margin

I have created an unordered list to store my images in but there a thin streak of white in between two of the lists. I don't know how there is space there so any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance!

[image]

### HTML

```
   <div class="montage">
       <ul>
        <li><img src="images/filler_image.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/filler_image.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/filler_image.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/filler_image.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/filler_image.jpg"/></li>
        <li><img src="images/filler_image.jpg"/></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

---

### CSS

```
 .montage {
   width:auto;
   overflow:hidden;
   position:relative;
   clear:both;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
 }

 .montage ul {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
 }

 .montage ul li {
   float:left;
   cursor:pointer;
   width:33.3333%;
   line-height: 0;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
 } 

 .montage ul li img {
   width:100%;
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   display:block;
   height:400px;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.0, 1.0);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's most likely this:  `width:33.3333%;` because the browser calculates a bit whacky sometimes. If you have scss or stylus or something for preprocessing, you can `width: (1/3)*100%;`

Here is a jsFiddle to isolate it:  https://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/or7bczdw/

Comment: Be aware of the default space that will appear between inline-block elements as well. : )   and - flex-box is also really great and could be used for this. Each approach has it's caveats.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flex box. Just set the containing element to `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap` and on the child elements (the `<li>`) set `flex-grow: 1;`

A reference on this is:
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/